# Selecting Regressors from list for time series

Tags: time-series, regression

I have been try to get results from a time series problem and I have used fb's prophet algo for that.
Now problem is I have to select comb of those regressors giving me least rmse.

I used granger causality test but somehow that is not giving as good results as that of combinations for rmse.

Any suggestion.

---

One alternative is to perform comb of features, add them as regressors via multiprocessing, which is still a lot.

any other way i can remove those features(in this case market time series ecnometric indexes)